# email form in php without opening email client

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make my email form to work but it doesn't. I found a ready `fromtoemail.php` files and I replaced the variables with mine. I tried a few online codes that I found but everyone gives me the same error. I get the error that my 1st field that it tracks it finds it null and I get the error message from my code instead of moving all through all the loops. I get the error here on the 1st line with if's

```
if($author == '') {print "You have not entered an author, please go back and try again";}
```

Here is the code from php and from me html.

PHP:

```
<?php 
 $to = $_REQUEST['myemail@gmail.com'] ; 
 $author = $_REQUEST['author'] ; 
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
 $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
 $text = $_REQUEST['text'] ;
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "$subject"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"author"} = "author"; 
 $fields{"email"} = "email"; 
 $fields{"subject"} = "subject"; 
 $fields{"text"} = "text"; 

 $body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 $headers2 = "$email"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.oursite.com";

 if($author == '') {print "You have not entered an author, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($email == '') {print "You have not entered a email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($subject == '') {print "You have not entered a subject, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($email, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($submit) 
 {header( "Location: http://www.sofisarti.com/index-english.html" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify webmaster@YourCompany.com"; } 
 }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

html:

```
 <form action="formtoemail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                            <p>
                                <label for="author">Name:</label> 
                                <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <p class="no_margin_right">
                                <label for="subject">Subject:</label> 
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" />
                            </p>
                            <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                            <label for="text">Message:</label> 
                            <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                            <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />
                      </form>
```

Comment: What is this doing?
 $fields{"author"} = "author";

Comment: Put `var_dump($_REQUEST);` right after your opening PHP tag and post the output.

Comment: Suggest you add error_reporting(E_ALL) to the top of the script.  There may be some reliance on undefined variables, and this will raise a notice about something like that.

Comment: This line `$to = $_REQUEST['myemail@gmail.com'] ;` is wrong, it should just be `$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';`.

Comment: @GillianLo-Wong See the `foreach` loop on the line after all those `$fields` settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this style of form validating. This should make things **more clear** and you'll be able to display **all the error messages at once**.

```
<?php 

$Author = $_POST['author'];
$Message = $_POST['text'];

$Errors = array();

if (strlen($Author) < 3){
    $Errors[] = 'Please enter your full name';
}

if (strlen($Message) < 10){
    $Errors[] = 'Please describe your message in more detail.';
}

// Add if- conditions for email, subject, etc..

if (!empty($Errors)){

    $Errorbody = '<ul>';
    foreach ($Errors as $Error){
        $Errorbody .= '<li>'.$Error.'</li>';    
    }
    $Errorbody .= '</ul>';
} else {
    // the rest of the stuff, sending email, header towards thank-you page.
}
?>

[HTML HEADER ETC]
<?php 
if (isset($Errorbody)){
    echo $Errorbody;
}
?>

[HTML FORM HERE]
```

Comment: thank you all for your replies. I will try out the codes you gave me and see what i get

Answer (score 0):

Here is my teaching example showing the essential parts of a form-to-email script.  Hope it helps you get things sorted out.  Best, ~Ray

```
<?php // RAY_form_to_email.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// SEND MAIL FROM A FORM


// REQUIRED VALUES ARE PREPOPULATED - CHANGE THESE FOR YOUR WORK
$from  = "NoReply@Your.org";
$subj  = "Contact Form";

// THIS IS AN ARRAY OF RECIPIENTS - CHANGE THESE FOR YOUR WORK
$to[]  = "You@Your.org";
$to[]  = "Her@Your.org";
$to[]  = "Him@Your.org";


// IF THE DATA HAS BEEN POSTED
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    // CLEAN UP THE POTENTIALLY BAD AND DANGEROUS DATA
    $email      = clean_string($_POST["email"]);
    $name       = clean_string($_POST["name"]);
    $telephone  = clean_string($_POST["telephone"]);

    // CONSTRUCT THE MESSAGE THROUGH STRING CONCATENATION
    $content    = NULL;
    $content   .= "You have a New Query From $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $content   .= "Tel No: $telephone" . PHP_EOL;
    $content   .= "Email: $email" . PHP_EOL;

    // SEND MAIL TO EACH RECIPIENT
    foreach ($to as $recipient)
    {
        if (!mail( $recipient, $subj, $content, "From: $from\r\n"))
        {
            echo "MAIL FAILED FOR $recipient";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "MAIL WORKED FOR $recipient";
        }
    }

    // PRODUCE THE THANK-YOU PAGE
    echo '<p>THANK YOU</p>' . PHP_EOL;
}


// A FORM TO TAKE CLIENT INPUT FOR THIS SCRIPT
$form = <<<ENDFORM
<form method="post">
Please enter your contact information
<br/>Email: <input name="email" />
<br/>Phone: <input name="telephone" />
<br/>Name:  <input name="name" />
<br/><input type="submit" />
</form>
ENDFORM;

echo $form;


// A FUNCTION TO CLEAN UP THE DATA - AVOID BECOMING AN OPEN-RELAY FOR SPAM
function clean_string($str)
{
    // IF MAGIC QUOTES IS ON, WE NEED TO REMOVE SLASHES
    $str = stripslashes($str);

    // REMOVE EXCESS WHITESPACE
    $rgx
    = '#'                // REGEX DELIMITER
    . '\s'               // MATCH THE WHITESPACE CHARACTER(S)
    . '\s+'              // MORE THAN ONE CONTIGUOUS INSTANCE OF WHITESPACE
    . '#'                // REGEX DELIMITER
    ;
    $str = preg_replace($rgx, ' ', $str);

    // REMOVE UNWANTED CHARACTERS
    $rgx
    = '#'                // REGEX DELIMITER
    . '['                // START OF A CHARACTER CLASS
    . '^'                // NEGATION - MATCH NONE OF THE CHARACTERS IN THIS CLASS
    . 'A-Z0-9'           // KEEP LETTERS AND NUMBERS
    . '"'                // KEEP DOUBLE QUOTES
    . "'"                // KEEP SINGLE QUOTES
    . '@&+:?_.,/\-'      // KEEP SOME SPECIAL CHARACTERS (ESCAPED HYPHEN)
    . ' '                // KEEP BLANKS
    . ']'                // END OF THE CHARACTER CLASS
    . '#'                // REGEX DELIMITER
    . 'i'                // CASE-INSENSITIVE
    ;
    $str = preg_replace($rgx, NULL, $str);

    return trim($str);
}
```